# Easiest way to Download SQL table to Excel C#

Tags: c#, sql

Whats the easiest way to download a sql table to excel as a button.  Just a Select * from tableA with all the data.

I want to use this format as well...

```
SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT QtyOnHand FROM Products.Products WHERE PartNumber like '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;

sqlCon2.Open();

//Download Excel Code

sqlCon2.Close();
```

Thank you and I appreciate it :)

Comment: Just create a comma-separated file, and Excel should be able to open it directly.

Comment: How would you do this? I'm not understanding. sorry

Comment: Bear in mind that what Branko proposed (although is undoubtedly the easiest option), is not exactly writing to Excel; but creating a file (CSV) which is supported by Excel. If you want to store just the information in rows/columns, this is the best answer; but bear in mind that it is not exactly Excel and thus cannot add any Excel feature (e.g., cell decoration, calculations, etc.). In case of wanting to export to "proper Excel", you would have to do some research by your own as far as this is not completely straightforward (and there are various alternatives).

Comment: PS: what Branko meant was: create a simple text file (with Streamwriter, for example), with all the rows you want and the columns separated by commas (save it as *.CSV).

Answer (score 2):

Execute your query in SSMS, select all the results, right click and **Save Results As...** which will allow you to save the results as a file.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, just output a comma-sparated file:

```
SqlConnection sqlCon2 = new SqlConnection("REMOVED");
SqlCommand sqlCmd2 = new SqlCommand();
sqlCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT QtyOnHand FROM Products.Products WHERE PartNumber like '" + textBox1.Text + "'";
sqlCmd2.Connection = sqlCon2;


sqlCon2.Open();

 using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"excelfile.csv"))
 {
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (reader.Read())
    {
       file.WriteLine(reader[0]);
    }

    reader.Close();
 }

sqlCon2.Close();
```